# Viper failing to create default config when config doesn't exist

Tags: go, viper-go

I am trying to create a default configuration file with viper if it doesn't already exist.

However, I am at a loss because viper seems to need this file to already exist.

I get the following error message:

```
Error writing config file: open /Users/zrbecker/.appname/config.yaml: no such file or directory
```

Here is the code I am trying to use.

```golang
func main() {
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("yaml")

    homeDir, err := os.UserHomeDir()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error getting home directory: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    configPath := filepath.Join(homeDir, ".appname")
    configFilePath := filepath.Join(configPath, "config.yaml")

    if err := os.MkdirAll(configPath, 0755); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to create config directory: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(configFilePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        if err := viper.SafeWriteConfigAs(configFilePath); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error writing config file: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `viper.WriteConfigAs(configFilePath)` works, since I am already checking that the file doesn't exist, this should be fine. However, my understanding is that "Safe" should write the file if it doesn't exist.

Maybe I don't understand.

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. On my system (ubuntu 22) it works fine. Check that `~/.appname` exists.

Comment: Works for me too. I am using Mac with 14.3.1 OS. maybe something related to permissions on your system?

Comment: you can use `github.com/gobuffalo/packr/v2` package for integrate a default config in built binary file , in this approach you will have a default config inside binary file and you can choose that programmatically at the production level